# AutoSuggestion in Combobox

Tags: c++, c, winapi, combobox, autosuggest

I created a Combobox with `CreateWindowEx`. Everything goes well. But I would like to make a final feature: AutoSuggestion. The Combobox is used to do search text in a document, hence at some point, it have items that are the strings a user searched. The AutoSuggestion should be: drop down the list of items, find those items that begin with the string that a user typed in the edit control, ***but do not select one of them***, do not display all other items, and finally do not change select item when keydown or keyup occurs, only highlight the item and select only when a user press `Enter`. Do you have any idea how to accomplish this task?

Comment: I can make drop down list show up when a user is typing, but for other stuff, don't know a way to achieve it. It seems to me that one can't hide item, only be able to remove it, which is not a good way to me.

Comment: So why can't you hide then re-add? Think outside the box, my friend.

Comment: you mean remove it, then re-add it?? Yes, I could. I just think it may not be a "good" way to do this, so I ask for better suggeston.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want [Autocomplete functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776884).

Comment: Yes Windows Explorer use Autocomplete for Combobox in Address Bar